# How to get the Clip Board Data from browser to my android app

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

> Hi,
>
> I am selecting the some text in my browser and copied to clipboard.
>   And I want to use this data in my application, when paste button
>   pressed the clipboard data will be pasted into my textview.
>
> And I am using the following code

```
    private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
    private ClipData myClip;
    myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
    ClipData abc = myClipboard.getPrimaryClip();
    ClipData.Item item = abc.getItemAt(0);
    String text = item.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("clip dataaa--->"+text);
```

> Any Idea? How to get the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Implement ClipboardListener to your ClipboardManager class.My sample code is below.

```
 ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener( new ClipboardListener() );

class ClipboardListener implements ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener
{

public void onPrimaryClipChanged()
{
String mPreviousText = "";
ClipData clipData = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip();
ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(0);
try{

if(item.getText()==null){

 System.out.println("if condition null value return---->");

}else{
mPreviousText=item.getText().toString();
System.out.println(" mPreviousText---->"+mPreviousText);
selectedText=item.getText().toString();
}

}catch (NullPointerException e) {
 // TODO: handle exception
  mPreviousText="";
 }}}
```